# How to remove a start up BIOS message that comes with pc

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, kernel

I got my pc from my job (education) and the first thing it shows when starting up is a white text message on a black screen "Ministry of Education" .
how do i remove it from my laptop ? it takes like 1.5 seconds from the booting time of the laptop

PS : Using Windows 10

Comment: They most likely added their logo to the UEFI partition.  Do a fresh install of Windows 10 and delete all partitions. The message should vanish. A fresh install is very much in order getting the machine from someone else.

Comment: If it doesn't change after doing the above then it has a modified firmware. You won't be able to change but that's not really a problem because if in the firmware then it's instead of of the default splash screen. It ISN'T delaying the boot process.

Comment: If you would like to replace the logo (which won't change the boot time), we need to know the model of your computer and your version of the BIOS. Success is not guaranteed, and my recommendation would be to leave it alone.